# How to enable text field when clicked based on radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have one text field and other three radio buttons.

I have to add amount for donation whether a custom amount filled from text box or whether by clicking a radio buttons which have fixed values.

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value = '1'>$1<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value = '5'>$5<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value = '10'>$10<br>
<input type = "number" id ="custom_amount">
```

I want to disable input field when any radio button is clicked and when I click on the text field it gets enabled.

Is it possible to do that? As i have tried using

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value = '1' id = 'id_1' onclick="document.getElementById('id_1').disabled = false; document.getElementById('custom_amount').disabled = true;">$1<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value = '5' id = 'id_5' onclick="document.getElementById('id_5').disabled = false; document.getElementById('custom_amount').disabled = true;">$5<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value = '10' id = 'id_10' onclick="document.getElementById('id_10').disabled = false; document.getElementById('custom_amount').disabled = true;">$10<br>
<input type = "number" id ="custom_amount">
```

Comment: `value = 1` change this to `value="1"` first

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you're trying to follow is not the standard, for the reason that it involves removing the selection from a radio group. While this is possible, it's not the intended use of a radio group, and is not very nice code.

For this reason the normal practice is to include an extra radio button which enables/disables the input when selected. Something like this:

```js
$('.radio').change(function() {
  $('#custom_amount').prop('disabled', !$(this).is('.other'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" class="radio" value="1">$1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" class="radio" value="5">$5</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" class="radio" value="10">$10</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" class="radio other" value="">Other:</label>
<input type="number" id="custom_amount" disabled="true">
```

Comment: Please give more detail that 'it doesn't work'. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Actually there is no error, in fact it doesn't alert anything

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Service unavailable (with message))
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at test.php:3

Comment: The 500 is a server side error which is unrelated to the JS code. $ is undefined means you haven't included jQuery.js in your page properly

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do like the below.by default the input element is not disabled and when any of the radio button is clicked and input box will be disabled

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Radio buttons input </title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="radio" class="radio" name="type" value = 1>$1<br>
 <input type="radio" class="radio" name="type" value = 5>$5<br>
 <input type="radio" class="radio" name="type" value = 10>$10<br>
 <input type = "number" id ="custom_amount" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
   $('.radio').on("click",function(){
       $('#custom_amount').val($(this).val());
        $('#custom_amount').attr("disabled","disabled");
        console.log($('#custom_amount').val());
   });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, But the solution you've provided is not what we actually want to perform.